# Uinput gamepad events not working

Tags: linux, archlinux, gamepad, uinput

How are you? I hope you can help me with something, I have a problem from Artix Linux, I want to connect my Wii Remote to use it as a Gamepad, it does not want to work because the uinput module does not want to interpret the events associated with Gamepad Inputs, it does not catch for example "BTN_A" or others, but if I put another as "KEY_A" if it recognizes it but acts as a keyboard input in that case. What solution do you propose?

Note that I use WMinput, and I have already installed cwiid, wminput, and even fixed the uinput module in the kernel.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site about programming and development. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming See [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) You should check Super User or Unix & Linux Stack Exchange as a better place to ask your question.

Comment: Yes, my mistake, I happened to eliminate the question or close it?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. In my case the error was that I tried to pass the button as an unsigned char. I realized later that BTN_A is not defined as 131 but as 0x131, so it doesn't fit into the unsigned char and gets truncated. Hope this helps!